# recognize newline with regex in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl, newline

I have an expression like:

```
ENTITY first
    VHDL language standard: 3 (VHDL-2008)
  ARCHITECTURE BODY arch
    VHDL language standard: 3 (VHDL-2008)
```

Now I want a regexp for only the first paranthesis after ENTITY
so the result should be `VHDL-2008` or even `2008`.

I'm new to regexps. What I tried:

```
"^ENTITY *(.*)"
```

only returns "first". So my question is: How can I request a newline after "first"?
My try:

```
"^ENTITY .*\\n(.*)"
```

And very confusing was the result of

```
"^(.*)"
```

which added some { and }. Why?

I have found a very ugly way to do this:

first eliminate newlines

```
set data [regsub -all "\n" $data ""]
```

and then something like this:

```
{ENTITY risc .*VHDL language standard: [0-3]..VHDL-(.*).}
```

As you can see I didn't understand how to recognize { or ( paranthesis. Any better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your expression is stored as a single string, you don't have to do anything special to accomodate newlines: the [`regexp` man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regexp.htm) says "By default, newline is a completely ordinary character with no special meaning."

To match the contents of the first set of parentheses, you can do:

```
% set str {ENTITY first
    VHDL language standard: 3 (VHDL-2008)
  ARCHITECTURE BODY arch
    VHDL language standard: 3 (VHDL-2008)}
% regexp {^ENTITY[^(]+\(([^)]+)} $str -> vhdl
1
% puts $vhdl
VHDL-2008
% # or use non-greedy matching
% regexp {^ENTITY.+?\((.+?)\)} $str -> vhdl
1
% puts $vhdl
VHDL-2008
```

Comment: And if the whole thing _isn't_ in a single string, you'll find getting a RE to match it very hard indeed.

Comment: thank you. I'll take regexp '{^ENTITY[^(]+\(VHDL-([^)]+)} $str -> vhdl' , to get only the number.

Comment: That won't work because the open parentheses before the VHDL is not escaped. If you only want the number, use `regexp {^ENTITY[^(]+\(VHDL-(\d+)} $str -> vhdlnum`

Comment: Well, it worked, but with \d is even better I guess. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`(`, `)`, `{`, and `}` are **metacharacters**. That means that for them to be recognized as normal characters, they have to be **escaped** with a `\` like this: `\(`, `\)`, `\{`, and `\}`.

On some operating systems, a new line is just `\n`, but on others, it is `\r\n`. A regex that will match both of those is `\r?\n`.

Try using this regex instead of `"^ENTITY .*\\n(.*)"`:

```
ENTITY(?:.*\\r?\\n)*?.*\\((.*)\\)
```

You can find a demo and explanation [here](http://regex101.com/r/jX0sK5).